# Wordpress media upload: insert uploaded file to post immediately after upload

Tags: media, wordpress

I need a minimal video upload mechanism in my plugin.

I use the built in media upload iframe:

```
tb_show("", "/wp-admin/media-upload.php?type=video&TB_iframe=true");
```

With fewer options:

```
add_filter('media_upload_tabs','dilute_media_upload_tabs');
function dilute_media_upload_tabs($tabs){
    return array(
        'type' => __('From Computer')
    );
}
```

I'd like to save the user from having to click on "Insert to post" button after every file upload, and instead, fire that event programmatically immediately after the file have been uploaded (or crunched or whatever...)

Any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: Also very interested in this, have been looking into the admin code but haven't been able to find a solution. I'm looking into a jQuery hack to get things working but not having much luck.